# Property setter not working in python 2

Tags: python, properties, setter

I have written a Python class but the setter doesn't seem to work.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property:

> A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods usable as
>   decorators that create a copy of the property with the corresponding
>   accessor function set to the decorated function. This is best
>   explained with an example:
>
> ```
> class C(object):
>     def __init__(self):
>         self._x = None
>
>     @property
>     def x(self):
>         """I'm the 'x' property."""
>         return self._x
>
>     @x.setter
>     def x(self, value):
>         self._x = value
>
>     @x.deleter
>     def x(self):
>         del self._x
> ```

My (example) class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class PropertyTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop_ = 5

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print "Getting prop plus one"
        return self.prop_ + 1

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, propValue):
        print "Assigning prop to " + propValue
        self.prop_ = propValue

t = PropertyTest()
print t.prop
t.prop = 10
print t.prop
```

Expected output:

> Getting prop plus one
>
> 6
>
> Assigning prop to 10
>
> Getting prop plus one
>
> 11

But what I get is this:

> Getting prop plus one
>
> 6
>
> 10

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Properties require *new-style* classes (inherit from `object`) to work properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you. I searched for duplicates but couldn't find anything. I read something about those "new-style" classes but didn't understand what it was about and disregarded it. Should I delete the question now?

Comment: That's up to you; duplicates can serve as sign-posts to the canonical post, so if someone googles for the exact terms you used in this post, they'd be directed to the other post automatically. In that way your post has value.

Comment: Thank you. I'll let this be, as the other question title isn't very descriptive ("python property getter/setter confusion")